# The right way to do remote (ajax) calls in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm making a Single Page Application with Ruby on Rails (it's my first ruby project ever so I'm definitely missing a lot of stuff yet). 
So I have a side menu with some links and the right part of the page is supposed to hold a container which is meant to be filled with some content of partial pages. 
The typical menu link I have now looks this way:

```
 <%= link_to t('my-groups'), :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'mygroups', :remote => true %>
```

I have a dashboard controller, here's the simplified version of it

```
 class DashboardController < ApplicationController
   def mygroups
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
  end
```

I have a dashboard template with the container div in it

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <h2>This is the default content of center page</h2>
</div>
```

And here's the routes.rb path for it:

```
get 'dashboard/mygroups' => 'dashboard#mygroups'
```

I also have one partial page alogside with my dashboard template and it's called _mygroups.html.erb and a javascript file mygroups.js.erb which is called as my controller action
look at the screenshot of the structure
[image]

The contents of this js.erb file are:

```
$('.right_col').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'mygroups')) %>");
```

It all works and the partial contents appear inside the container on link click just fine. 
But there are still 2 problems I couldn't google the answer for

**The questions part:**

1) It works with Ajax call but if I simply put this http://localhost:3000/dashboard/mygroups to my browser's navigation line and hit enter, it will give me this error

> ActionController::UnknownFormat in DashboardController#mygroups
>   ActionController::UnknownFormat
>
> Extracted source (around line #70):
>
> def mygroups
>       respond_to do |format|
>         format.js    end   end

How can I avoid this and just redirect to index in this case? 
I understand that ajax uses POST, but I tried to use post instead of get in routes.rb for this action, and it didn't work at all

2) What if I have a lot of actions for different partial pages, do I have to create a new js.erb file for each action? Can't it be done in some simplier way with just one file?

3) Is it possible to not specify controller and action on this link explicitly?

```
<%= link_to t('my-groups'), :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'mygroups', :remote => true %>
```

I mean since it's supposed to be a POST ajax request, how come I need to display the url like this http://localhost:3000/dashboard/mygroups to a user?

Comment: `.js.erb` is the messiest way to do it. Instead do it with JSON data and have the functions in your client-side script, not served up as responses.

Comment: add format.html also

Comment: eg respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
   end

Comment: you can add url in link_to tag like <%= link_to t('my-groups'), '/dashboard/mygroups', :remote => true %>

Comment: @tadman, could you, please, be more specific? Maybe give some example code. I have no idea of how to do this, as I'm new to Ruby and to Rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add format.html in controller like:

```
 class DashboardController < ApplicationController
   def mygroups
    if request.xhr?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
       end
    else 
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

you can add url in link_to tag like:

```
<%= link_to t('my-groups'), '/dashboard/mygroups', :remote => true %>
```

Comment: What does format.html change? I didn't notice any changes. Could you explain that? As to '/dashboard/mygroups' it does not make any difference. It will still create a link, so it doesn't answer my question

Comment: DashboardController#mygroups is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: I don't want it to open the page. I need this request to be redirected to "/" if it's not made with ajax

Comment: '/dashboard/mygroups' in link_to tag remove the controller and action name in it

Comment: you have to create .html.erb file. If you want to redirect to "/" then write code: redirect_to root_url unless request.xhr?

Comment: Thanks! That answerd one of my questions :)

Comment: I also answered your third question. Have you looked?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to you questions

1. When you hit the URL in browser, it sends vanilla HTTP get request(non-ajax) which your controller action is not configured to handle it. You need to add `format.html` and template named `groups.html.erb` where generally you will list all the groups, I guess.

`respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end`

2. Ideally you have to create separate file for each action but if you can take something common out of different action then you can move common template code to a partial and render it either in a separate template having something special or from the controller action directly.
3. Yes. The rails way is to use routes helper. Run `rake routes` to list all available routes in your app and find relevant helpers.

I would strongly suggest to read the rails guide to understand how everything works.

Comment: I'm reading the docs all the time. But I can't physically read and understand it all at once, so sorry if the answers is there on the docs, I just couldn't find it.